# Unable to delete vagrant on Ubuntu

Tags: vagrant

Here's what I've tried to remove vagrant on Ubuntu 20.

```
   sudo apt remove vagrant
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove vagrant
   sudo dpkg -r vagrant
```

and from https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html
I've tried `rm -rf /opt/vagrant` (which does not exist).

After all that I still get:

```
vagrant

Usage: vagrant [options] <command> [<args>]

    -v, --version                    Print the version and exit.
    -h, --help                       Print this help.
```

Comment: do a `which vagrant`. This will give you the path of the vagrant executable. It might be a symbolic link. If it is then just follow the link to its actual location.

Comment: /home/snowcrash/bin/vagrant is a regular file.
Do you just `rm` it?

Comment: Yeah it should work. But this only deletes the executable. There should also be a `.vagrant` or `.vagrant.d` folder in your home. Its where vagrant stores its metadata like boxes and all. You can optionally choose to remove it.

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html. This is actually mentioned in the docs. Adding it here for future references